# Trouble referencing with Bibtex and TeXstudio

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

All right, this is driving me crazy... I have thesis example template with one reference that I'm trying to compile with [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7.

My thesis template looks like this:

```
...a bunch of text
This is some more text \cite{greenwade93}.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}
...
```

My references are in References.bib:

```
@article{greenwade93,
author  = "George Greenwade",
title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year    = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume  = "14",
number  = "3",
pages   = "342--351"
}
```

**The bibliography shows up with the reference at the end of my thesis and the .bbl file looks fine. However, the citation in the text is just a bolded question mark.**

I do get a warning that:

```
"Latex Warning: Citation 'greenwade93' on page 4 undefined on input line 810."
```

This is my thesis.bbl file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{greenwade93}
George Greenwade.
\newblock The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN}).
\newblock {\em TUGBoat}, 14(3):342--351, 1993.

\end{thebibliography}
```

This is my thesis.blg file:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: References.bib
```

The thesis.aux also looks fine to me... The last few lines of the .aux file are:

```
\bibstyle{plain}
\bibdata{References}
\bibcite{greenwade93}{1}
\HyPL@Entry{15<</P(6)>>}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{Bibliography}{6}{subsection.4.3.2}}
```

I've searched here and through google for this problem and have found lots... But most of the answer seem to be to run Latex > Bibtex > Latex > Latex

But that is what I'm already doing I think, so I'm stumped. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If I build with your information snippets a minimal example it works fine. So the problem lies in something you are not telling. So try to make a small but complete example.

Comment: You are probably removing the `.aux` file prior to running LaTeX again.

Comment: When I run the minimum example using TeXStudio, I get the same problem, so it is to do with TeXStudio and the way it is configurated...

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem. I solved it by setting the path of the `bibtex.exe` as the following steps:

1. click the Options menu
2. click Configuration TeXstudio
3. click Command and the enter the path of `bibtex.exe` in your machine, for example its path in my PC is `C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/bibtex.exe`, you can enter it as follows:

   ```
   "C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/bibtex.exe  " %
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same thing happen to me after installing texstudio on my new pc.  I ran it in the command prompt so I could see the errors (must be a way to do this in texstudio, but whatever)...

```
pdfatex mytexfile  
bibtex mytexfile
```

turns out I had two problems:

1) my bibstyle `hplain.bst` wasn't being found (probably not your problem but you could try using "bibliographystyle{c:/blablabla/plain}", where blablabla would be the path to the `plain.bst` found by typing `plain.bst` into google.

2) there were some error in the `.bib` file I referenced in `mytexfile.tex`

I fixed these two problems and presto!  Don't know why my bibtex previously ran back when I used to use the command line version installed on my terminal at work, but either way it works now.  I think the thing it was most mad about was my use of % to comment things, which apparently is not appropriate in BibTeX.

Anyways... hopes this helps someone out there.  Toodles.

Answer (score 1):

I had a related problem -- my citations were not visible in the main PDF. To fix this I removed the empty spaces in the filename of my .bib and re-referenced it in the main .tex file. This worked.

old filename: "my references.bib"
new filename: "myRef.bib"

Of course, changed the main.tex file's `\bibliography{myRef}` to include the new filename.

Hope this helps.

Sai

Answer (score 1):

I had a related problem, and a Google search led me to this question ... so I will leave my solution here, in case others run into the same problem. I was using TeXstudio and running BibTeX but no references or citations were showing up. No errors popped up when compiling.

The problem was that I was using

```
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

instead of

```
\bibliography{references}
```

so TeXstudio was looking for a file `references.bib.bib`, which of course did not exist.

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Apparently I was having the same problem.