# How do I make Bibtex work with Texstudio?

Tags: bibtex

I'm using texstudio 2.11.2 with ubuntu.  All with templates.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
Blablab \cite {{N}obody 1111}.  BlabBlabBlab \cite{{A}nybody 2222}
\begin{thebibliography}
  @book{Nobody 1111,
        author = {Nobody},
        title = {nothing},
        date = {1111},
    }
@book{Anybody 2222,
    author = {Anybody},
    title = {Something},
    date = {2222},
}
\end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

and I get

> Blablab [?].  Blablablab [?]
>
> References
>
> bookNobody 1111, author = Nobody, title = nothing, date = 1111
>   @bookNothing 2222, author = Anybody, title = Something, Date = 2222

Missing "@"  is not a typo.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/306229/134144

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend reading the following page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Short summary/analysis of your code snippet:

- The contents you put in the environment `\begin{thebibliography}` must go in a separate file (e.g. `references.bib`). The Embedded system you use, usually goes with `\bibitem{AuthorYear` entries.
- Your citation keys `Nobody 1111` should not have spaces
- When your references and your document are separate, you need to first run `pdflatex file.tex`, followed by `bibtex file.tex` and another `pdflatex file.tex`

When compiling your document with BibTeX fails, refer to [Trouble referencing with Bibtex and TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44359/trouble-referencing-with-bibtex-and-texstudio)